# Error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.' al hacer un UPDATE en Visual Basic

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, update

Estoy realizando un UPDATE y al parecer tengo un problema en la sintaxis sin embargo este error no me dice nada. Mi código del botón update es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim query As String = "
UPDATE Articulo 
SET Descripcion = @descripcion, Fecha_Ingreso = @fecha, Valor = @valor, Stock_Minimo = @stock, Codigo_Bodega = @bodega)
WHERE Codigo = artid
"
        Dim artid As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextCodigo.Text)
        Dim descripcion As String = TextDescripcion.Text
        Dim fecha As DateTime = DateTimePickerinsert.Value
        Dim valor As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextValor.Text)
        Dim stock As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextStock.Text)
        Dim bodega As String = ComboBodega.Text

        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-RDQIL7L3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Bodega;Integrated Security=True"),
          command As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            command.Parameters.Add("@artid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = artid
            command.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextDescripcion.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@fecha", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fecha
            command.Parameters.Add("@valor", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = valor
            command.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stock
            command.Parameters.Add("@bodega", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBodega.Text
            con.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Modificado correctamente")
        LoadDataInGrid()
    End Sub
```

Al tratar de modificar uno de los registros obtengo el error mencionado en el título:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near '('.'

Los nombres de las columnas en mi tabla son estos por si sirve de algo:

```
Tabla Articulo

Codigo
Descripcion
Fecha_Ingreso
Valor
Stock_Minimo
Codigo_Bodega
```

Soy nuevo en esto y el update es lo único que no funciona en mi proyecto, por lo que cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: El error es bastante explicativo, tienes un paréntesis que no va, acá: `Codigo_Bodega = @bodega)`

Comment: Adicionalmente no esta pasando artid como parametro, le falta la arroba en la consulta

Comment: Eso era, tenia un ) demás y faltaba el @ en artid de la consulta....muchisimas gracias por los comentarios